# C# CodeDom Double Type Reference

Tags: c#, types, codedom

I am able to make a call to some type by using `CodeMethodInvokeExpression` along with `CodeTypeReferenceExpression`, but I would like to be able to make a reference to the following line of code:

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = "FilePath";
```

Here is what I've got so far -

```
CodeVariableDeclarationStatement statement = new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(typeof(System.Diagnostics.Process), "p",
    new CodeObjectCreateExpression("System.Diagnostics.Process",
    new CodeExpression[] { }));
```

I cannot figure out how to produce the line "p.StartInfo.FileName = exFilePath" for the life of me.

Any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Evan

Comment: why not produce `p.StartInfo.FileName = exFilePath` with [`CodeAssignStatement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.codeassignstatement.aspx)?

Comment: @vlad I have considered that but I can't figure out how to generate the "p.startinfo.filename" part of that ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
new CodeAssignStatement(
    new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
        new CodePropertyReferenceExpression(
              new CodeVariableReferenceExpression("p"),
              "StartInfo"),
        "FileName"),
    new CodePrimitiveExpression("FilePath"))
```

should do.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for . CodePropertyReferenceExpression. I will give this a go - thank you very much

Comment: Hope this helps. I'm not very experienced with CodeDom.